# Getting 404 not found on Flask app deployed on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, pythonanywhere

I've rummaged through maybe 50 different answers to this and still I haven't manage to fix it... I'm pretty new to flask and python.

I have an app which was running great locally but I've struggled with deploying on python anywhere. Initially I had a few import modules issues, now it runs but doesn't return any html template, despite not seeing any other issue. The main issue I had was that it couldn't find the "routes" app from wsgi, and I sort of fixed adding the app = Flask(**name**) line on routes.py (the short blueprint object is not callable).

routes.py:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request, redirect, send_file
import pyqrcode 
from pyqrcode import QRCode 
import subprocess

from extensions import db
from models import Link

app = Flask(__name__)

short = Blueprint('short', __name__, url_prefix='/')

@short.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

**init**.py

```
from flask import Flask
from extensions import db
from routes import short

def create_app(config_file='settings.py'):

    app = Flask(__name__)

    app.config.from_pyfile(config_file)

    db.init_app(app)

    app.register_blueprint(short)

    return app
```

wsgi.py

```
import sys

# add your project directory to the sys.path
project_home = u'/home/b297py/mysite'

if project_home not in sys.path:
    sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path

# import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from routes import app as application
```

For the purpose of testing, I've placed all the html templates both in the root directory and in the specific /template directory but it just didn't fix the issue.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could also add a screenshot with the address you're trying to get and the error message (even though it is 404)

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderPushkarev I'm getting the following message: 
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again. I'm trying to connect to the mysite.pythonanywhere.com, in this case b297py.pythonanywhere.com,

Answer (score 1):

In wsgi.py you are not calling `create_app` so you are never registering the blueprint. You should replace :

```
from routes import app as application
```

by something like :

```
from package_name import create_app
application = create_app()
```

(Example: https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/12889/#id_post_50171)

Also as you mentioned, the fix adding `app = Flask(__name__)` to `routes.py`allows you to bypass create_app (so you should remove it if you want to stick to the create_app approach).

Comment: thanks @JBLaf. Do I need to import the create_app function I've created in the init.py? I've tried doing so and I get an error: ´Error running WSGI application
2020-04-26 20:45:43,441: AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint function: short.index´
2020-04-26 20:45:43,441:   File "/var/www/b297py_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 18, in <module>
2020-04-26 20:45:43,441:     application = create_app(). I've checked the Flask documentation and it seems I've got nothing off [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.0.x/tutorial/factory/)

Comment: Yes you have to import this one. Did you delete the other Flask object creation in routes.py.
You might need to have a look to https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xv-a-better-application-structure or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications : app/__init__.py is the one you are after (and then import it in wsgi.py with from app import create_app

Comment: thanks JBLaf. Eventually I've sorted it out recreating the virtualenv and setting up the wsgi file.